# How to correctly pass parameters to change the page on the API with React

Tags: reactjs, api, flask

I have this button inside a react component, and I call the fetchImages function with it

```
                  <button onClick={() => this.fetchImages()} 
                     type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mt-4">
                    Mais Imagens
                  </button>
```

FetchImages is a function where I use axios to make a get request on a FLASK API, to get all the itens in one page

```
fetchImages(page) {
const { filters } = this.state;
this.setState({ loadingFetchImages: true });
const { headers } = getAxiosConfig();
axios.get(`${API_URL}/api/imagens_selecionadas`, { params: { page, q: 
filters }, headers })
.then((response) => {
  const images = response.data.objects.map(image => ({ ...image, check: 
 false }));
  this.setState({ images, loadingFetchImages: false });
  })
.catch(handleRequestError);
```

}

I need to found a way to, everytime the user click the button, the page advance with the parameter ?page=1, ?page=2, etc. So i need to call http://localhost:5000/api/imagens_selecionadas?page=1, ?page=2 and etc...

I cant found a way to do that, can someone help me?

Comment: If I understood your question you want to change the URL correct?  If that is the case you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries unless you are using react-router then it's best to use it's own history management functions.

Answer (score 0):

you can define a store for your component and save your variable and constant inside it. if you pass your store via your component, you  always have every critical and necessary variable you want